# Is it risky to use a cell-phone in a hospital?

Tags: radiation, mobile-phones

Cell phones are forbidden in a lot of hospitals because they interfere with the medical instruments. I've found studies that prove both that it's dangerous and both that it's not:

- [No, it's not dangerous.](http://www.gizmag.com/go/6979/)
- [Yes, it is](http://www.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,1659417,00.html)

These researches seem to contradict each other. So are there any known cases where people were hurt by someone using a cellphone in a hospital? And if there is, why are microwave ovens, radio/tv signals, wifi signals OK?

Comment: the second link, in second to last paragraph it says they're not in real world scenarios

Comment: When I was working in the hospital they often said the rule was to help in peace and quiet as much as anything else :)

Comment: One of my friends is a nurse, and I asked her if she knows if cellular phones really do interfere with equipment.  She'd heard that there was some older equipment in the department she works in that would malfunction when an active cellular phone was near it, but that equipment eventually got replaced with a newer model.  **Since it's reasonable to assume that equipment at hospitals are important for saving lives, I prefer to error on the side of caution and respect the "shut off cellular phones" rule in the interest of not causing problems for patients.**

Comment: Seems it is a "Potential" problem...http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/HomeBusinessandEntertainment/CellPhones/ucm116311.htm

Comment: Snopes info...http://www.snopes.com/horrors/techno/hospital.asp

Comment: @Moab:  +1 for finding a government source as these tend to have extra credibility.

Comment: I've been doing it for years but that's just anecdotal.

Comment: Also anecdotal but as i send this i have attatched a 12 lead ekg to myself. It is not any different than the control i did ten minutes ago.

Comment: Hospitals often sell phone-service to astronomical costs. And sell the roof of their building to telcos, to place their antennas, which work with much higher energies than your small device, at least, if your device is some meters from the device to interfere with away.

Comment: @user unknown:  A microwave transceiver on the rooftop is a permanent installation that doesn't move so it is more predictable (and measures can be taken to install shielding or upgrade equipment where needed).  People using handheld cellular phones, on the other hand, do exhibit movement due to walking around, using elevators, or just moving their heads or switching ears while sitting still.  _Regardless of the Hospital's reasons, if they have a rule about not using cellular phones (or smoking, for example) in the hallways, then adhering to these rules clearly is the preferred choice._

Comment: Medical practitioners in standby use mobile devices for a long time, and normal consumer equipment today. If you prefer to believe, that these devices magically turn into harmless mode, when used by a doctor, you might find it the clearly preferred choice - I don't, and prefer to stay skeptic. If you believe the hospitals perform measurements when standard technical equipment is installed close to them - please, do so; I don't.

Comment: I agree with @user unknown.  Doctors use cell phones and pagers all the time in the hospital.  Not only that, but wireless networks are also very prevalent in hospitals these days. If there was truly a risk to human life, I would think that they would confiscate them at the door,  or have hefty fines for their use.

Comment: @Kibbee:  My pager doesn't utilize microwave transmissions, and I'm not aware of any that do operate on the same wavelengths as cellular phones.  My understanding is that pagers are safe where cellular phones could cause some problems (that's one of a few reasons I chose to have my pager take all incoming calls).

Comment: @RR: all digital pagers operate on roughly the same frequencies as do cellphones (analog pagers operate on the lower frequencies used by analog mobile phone networks) and often share the same networks. If pagers are safe, so are cellphones.

Comment: I have to agree with UU here. Doctors and nurses use cellphones all the time, including while standing next to patients and the equipment they're hooked up to. And nowadays they're starting to use their WiFi and 3G enabled tablets as well while in the wards, keeping patient records etc. on them rather than on paper. If those are safe, why are cellphones brought in by patients and visitors inherently unsafe? No, the $5 per minute cost for even local calls of the rental phones hospitals provide patients are most likely the real reason (in the past this may have been different).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FDA in the USa says there are "potential" risks with Pacemakers and Defibrillators

> Interference with Pacemakers and Other Medical Devices
>
> Potential interference:
>
> Radiofrequency energy (RF) from cell phones can interact with some electronic devices. This type of interference is called electromagnetic interference (EMI). For this reason, FDA helped develop a detailed test method to measure EMI of implanted cardiac pacemakers and defibrillators from cell phones. This test method is now part of a standard sponsored by the Association for the Advancement of Medical Instrumentation (AAMI). This standard will allow manufacturers to ensure that cardiac pacemakers and defibrillators are safe from cell phone EMI.
>
> FDA continues to monitor the use of cell phones for possible interactions with other medical devices. Should harmful interference be found to occur, FDA will conduct testing to assess the interference and work to resolve the problem.
>
> Precautions for pacemaker wearers
>   If EMI were to occur, it could affect a pacemaker in one of three ways:
>   Stopping the pacemaker from delivering the stimulating pulses that regulate the heart's rhythm
>
> Causing the pacemaker to deliver the pulses irregularly
>
> Causing the pacemaker to ignore the heart's own rhythm and deliver pulses at a fixed rate
>
> But based on current research, cell phones would not seem to pose a significant health problem for the vast majority of pacemaker wearers. Still, people with pacemakers may want to take some simple precautions to be sure that their cell phones don't cause a problem.
>   Hold the phone to the ear opposite the side of the body where the pacemaker is implanted to add some extra distance between the pacemaker and the phone
>   Avoid placing a turned-on phone next to the pacemaker implant (e.g. don’t carry the phone in a shirt or jacket pocket directly over the pacemaker)
>
> Related Links
>
> [Electromagnetic Compatibility](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationSafety/ElectromagneticCompatibilityEMC/default.htm)

[Source of Information](http://www.fda.gov/Radiation-EmittingProducts/RadiationEmittingProductsandProcedures/HomeBusinessandEntertainment/CellPhones/ucm116311.htm)

Comment: They (the FDA) also discourages cellular phone use by children (yet they also state that there are no known health risks for children using cellular phones).

Answer (score 5):

The [UK Department of Health guidance](http://www.dh.gov.uk/en/Publicationsandstatistics/Publications/PublicationsPolicyAndGuidance/DH_092811) was changed a couple of years ago to discourage hospital-wide bans for which there was never really any justification. The major worries are not electromagnetic interference but privacy and basic electrical safety (or even: what happens if patients unplug essential equipment to charge their phones?)

Overall conclusion:

> The working presumption should be that patients will be allowed the widest possible use of mobile phones in hospitals, including on wards, where the local risk assessment indicates that such use would not represent a threat to patients’ own safety or that of others, the operation of electrically sensitive medical devices in critical care situations and the levels of privacy and dignity that must be the hallmark of all NHS care.

The report does record a handful of example of possible interference with devices, but few can be attributed with certainty to a mobile phone and several probably require a faulty medical device for phone interference to be a problem.

Comment: That's a great reference. It would be good to quote some passages from it; especially to support your claims about the major worries. I notice it does say "The Medicines and Healthcare products Regulatory Agency (MHRA) does not advise that NHS trusts should operate a hospital-wide ban but has said that in certain circumstances the electromagnetic interference from mobile phones can interfere with some devices, particularly if used within 2 metres of such devices. It has issued a number of reference documents relating to this" (references included)